# BMC Remedy Service Desk Integration with Sailpoint

Tags: integration, remedy, sailpoint

I am working on a new project and need some information. We are going to integrate sailpoint with BMC Remedy Service desk. we would like to give access to user through Remedy, Where we provide access request and then sailpoint provision them to the defined (groups or entitlements). I would like to get more knowledge how can we do that I went through sailpoint documentation to understand but I would like to visualize whats going on.
for example:
I have one user and would like to give him access to "IT-department" in order to do that I have to provision him into "IT-department" entitlement of Active Directory. I want to use BMC Remedy to give him access request to "IT-department". I want to understand how BMC remedy will be able to tell sailpoint to provision to specific entitlements and automate this process.

Any idea and suggestion will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I didnty get any answer but I was able to find it through some search.
Answer will be using REST API to call workflow